# PHP5.6 and APC installation

Tags: php, apc

How to install APC under PHP 5.6?

APC is installed

```
apt-get install php-pear php5-dev make libpcre3-dev
pecl install apc

# locate apc.so
/usr/lib/php5/20100525/apc.so
```

APC is added to php.ini

```
extension=apc.so
```

But APC is not mentioned in output from `phpinfo()`

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function apc_fetch()
```

Comment: Don't install APC with PHP 5.6, because you have OpCache as an opcode cache instead. If you need APC for user data, then use APCu

Comment: What is APCu and is it bundled with PHP 5.6? I don't want to rewrite old code which use APC

Comment: No, it isn't bundled with PHP 5.6.... its a userdata only version of APC (none of the opcode caching because that's handled now by OpCache), but 100% compatible with the old APC for caching data from within your code

Comment: Ok.. But how to install apcu?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-5.6

Comment: @MarkBaker APC is MUCH more than opcode cache. `apc_fetch()` illustrates that. It's still useful in 5.6, but not for opcode cache.

Comment: @Rudie - I'm aware of that, though its limitation is cache per server, so I currently use Redis for data caching in a multi-server environment

Comment: @MarkBaker Indeed. Smart. Is that a common practice?

Comment: Not sure it's common practise, but it's pretty useful, and redis might not be quite as fast as APCu but it's pretty close.... I even use it for sessions, so it doesn't matter which webhead a user hits, their session is maintained regardless

Answer (score 10, accepted):

APC is (more or less) a deprecated package (the last release, 3.1.14, [was unstable](http://news.php.net/php.internals/65616) and had to be rolled back). It has been replaced by the core package opcache.

I'm not sure about Debian flavors (all my searches return the PECL library while opcache is native to 5.6) but in CentOS you have to install the `php-opcache` package, which contains the opcahce.so file.

Comment: `apt-get install php5-apcu` worked for me on Debian wheezy :D

Comment: PHP 5.6.x: activate APCu, installing is not enough. [read more](http://www.christianroessler.net/tech/2015/php-5-6-x-activate-apcu.html)

Comment: OpCache is not a full blown cache, like APC, it's a simple opcode cache with some optimization steps. And it's not a userland cache - "just" an internal cache, speeding the processing of PHP up.

Comment: @MarceloRodovalho Maybe I missed something, but nobody here is talking about web server caching

Comment: I use APCu to cache data... OPCache doesn't.

Comment: @Loenix Yes, but the question was about APC, not APCu

Answer (score 4):

It works for me

```
yum install php56w-pecl-apcu
```

Comment: Just an FYI, but APCu is not exactly the same thing as APC. [APCu is APC stripped of opcode caching.](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu)

Answer (score 4):

For Amazon Linux, The below command worked for me.

yum install php56-pecl-apcu

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by others on this question, on PHP 5.6, you probably don't want the full APC package. Instead, you almost certainly just want the user-data caching portion, APCu.

If you're using PECL, you need to specify the correct version of APCu to use which appears to be 4.0.11:

```
pecl install apcu-4.0.11
```

(Worked for me on CentOS 6, EasyApache 3, Apache 2.2, PHP 5.6.39. )

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04 simply running

`sudo apt install php-apcu`

and enabling it on `/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini` by adding this lines at the end of the file:

```
extension=apcu.so
apc.enabled=1
```

(and restarting apache2 if necessary)

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04 this worked for me:

1. Download [rpm from here](http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/remi/x86_64//php56-php-pecl-apcu-devel-4.0.11-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm)
2. install alien to able to install rpm

```
    sudo apt-get install alien
```

3. install apcu

```
    sudo alien -i ~/Downloads/php56-php-pecl-apcu-4.0.11-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm
```

4. open apcu.ini

```
    sudo nano /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini
```

5. add these lines to enable apcu

```
    extension=apcu.so
    apc.enabled=1
    apc.enable_cli=1
```